# Documenting a module interface with multiple implementations

Tags: python, pydoc

I am a maintainer of a Python module that provides an operating system-agnostic API. There are internal modules that implement this interface for each supported OS.

There is a package and `__init__.py` looks something like:

```py
if sys.platform == "win32":
    from .win32_backend import *
elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
    from .darwin_backend import *

fib.__doc__ = 'Calculates the nth Fibonacci number'
```

The docstrings are set here so that the documentation does not need to be duplicated in each of the backend modules.

It feels a little sloppy to me to do it this way. Alternatively, we could have something like this, but it feels like a lot of boilerplate.

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    import .win32_backend as backend
elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
    import .darwin_backend as backend

def fib(n):
    '''Calculates the nth Fibonacci number'''
    return backend.fib(n)
```

Is there a preferred "Pythonic" way to document an interface with multiple implementations?

Comment: Hmm, so like the opposite of [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)

Comment: Your question already has two fine alternatives. Unless you operationalize "sloppy", I'm not sure what you need. Pydoc works off of live data. If there were a documentation engine that didn't run the code, then this issue would be moot.